# null parameters miscounts id on nodes

Tags: java

So for my cs class we need to make a family tree with nodes with two nodes as roots. Every-time a node is created it has a unique id and the counter will keep increasing for every new node. I have a question regarding instantiating a class and setting items to null and counting every time a new node is created.

```
public class Node<T> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
// instance variables
static int instanceCounter = 0;
int id = 0;
private T element;
private Node<T> fparent;
private Node<T> sparent;
private List<Node<T>> children;


public Node() {
    instanceCounter++;
    id = instanceCounter;
    this(null, null, null, null, null); // -> this does not work
}

public Node(T element) {
    this.element = element;
    instanceCounter++;
    id = instanceCounter;
}

public Node(T element, Node<T> fparent, Node<T> sparent, List<Node<T>> children) {
    instanceCounter++;
    id = instanceCounter;
    this.element = element;
    this.setFparent(fparent);
    this.setSparent(sparent);
    this.setChildren(children);
}
```

However this works:

```
   public Node() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null);
    instanceCounter++;
    id = instanceCounter;
}
```

What I want is :

Node 1 : Id = 1
Node 2 : Id = 2
Node 3 : Id = 3

but this what I get when the node instantiated with nothing in the parameters:

Node 1 : Id = 2
Node 2 : Id = 3
Node 3 : Id = 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instanceCounter is incremented twice when you call the default constructor. You should change your default constructor code to.

```
public Node() {
    instanceCounter++;
    id = instanceCounter;
    //No call required here as all elements are already null
}
```